# Android app running shows a black window with shut down buttons

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on my new app with android studio but when I run the app I get this black window:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovJCL.png)

Comment: hi Itay, can you elaborate little more about your problem as in, what were you accessing or action you are performing.

Comment: Sure! I just made a simple layout and I try to see how it runs, instead of showing my layout it's just showing this black screen in the screenshot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.